# Auth0 bundling with Aurelia skeleton

Tags: gulp, aurelia, bundling-and-minification, auth0, jspm

**Goal**:

- integrate Auth0
- successfully execute **gulp bundle-serve** and **gulp export-serve** for aurelia-skeleton-navigation

**Observed behavior/issue**:

- Unbundled app works as expected.
- As soon as I bundle/export, exception thrown when attempting to bundle

**Repro Steps**:

*I ran into the issue on my current app in development, so I stepped back to avoid my app-specific code for muddying the waters, and started with a fresh version of skeleton-esnext*

1. github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext to my  local folder
2. npm install, jspm install -y  (*npm & jspm already installed globally*)
3. jspm install github:auth0/lock  (*NOTE* the readme.MD states "*After installing the auth0-lock module, you'll need bundle it up along with all of its dependencies. We have examples for browserify and webpack.*" - I am not using the webpack aurelia skeleton, nor do I have browserify as a package currently.  I re-ran jspm install to ensure all packages were installed for a non bundled serve command)
4. Adding a callback route to **app.js** that's mapped to **Allowed Callback URLs** in Auth0 Client Settings (localhost:9000/#/auth-cb): {route: "auth-cb", moduleId: "welcome", name:"auth-cb"}
5. Create Authentication module, to be imported to welcome module, handling login/logout. Insert "Login" button on welcome html page to trigger auth.login()
6. run gulp serve command, page behaves as expected (takes me to Auth0, allows me to select my Google login, returns me to SPA which recognizes I have authenticated, & redirects me successfully to the users page)
7. Non bundled scripts appear as:

```
--jspm_packages
  --github
    --auth0
      --lock@10.16.0/build
          -lock.js
      -lock@10.16.0.js
```

8. run gulp serve-bundle command, exception:

```
Error on dependency parsing for github:auth0/lock@10.16.0/build/lock.js at file:///F:/source/aurelia_es-next-auth0_skeleton/jspm_packages/github/auth0/lock@10.16.0/build/lock.js
        Loading github:auth0/lock@10.16.0.js
        Error: Multiple anonymous defines.
    at ParseTreeTransformer.AMDDependenciesTransformer.transformCallExpression (F:\source\aurelia_es-next-auth0_skeleton\node_modules\systemjs-builder\compilers\amd.js:98:13)...
```

What do I need to modify in my bundles.js file or in my gulp build task to ensure that all dependent files are built/bundled correctly?

Public GitHub repo:  https://github.com/jaundiced/so-aurelia-auth0-bundling

Comment: Have you made _any_ edits to your bundle.js file yet?

Comment: @thebluefox: Here's what I have for my updated bundles.js [link](https://github.com/jaundiced/so-aurelia-auth0-bundling/blob/master/build/bundles.js): 
       
        `"dist/aurelia": {
            "includes": [ ... ,
                "jquery",
                "auth0/lock"
            ],`

Comment: What if you move those 2 into the `app/build` section of your Bundle config instead

Comment: @thebluefox - just tried moving the 2 from aurelia bundle to app bundle. Still throwing the same error: `Loading github:auth0/lock@10.16.0.js  Error: Multiple anonymous defines`

Comment: @thebluefox full **bundles.js**  block: `module.exports = {
    "bundles": {
        "dist/app-build": {
            "includes": [
                "[**/*.js]",
                "**/*.html!text",
                "**/*.css!text",
                "jquery",
                "auth0/lock"
            ],
            "options": {
                "inject": true,
                "minify": true,
                "depCache": true,
                "rev": false
            }
        },
        "dist/aurelia": { `  _etc_